# Spring project migration java 1.8 to java 11 (tomcat running error)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat

In this migration I am using eclipse IDE. This spring project does not use *pom.xml* file. So need to add .jar files manually.
First I set eclipse installed JREs in java 11.0.8. After changing this, project will show some errors.
After adding *jaxb-api-2.2.3.jar* project errors doesn't appear. Then after project clean and build, there is no any error.
Then I set new tomcat9 server and JRE version is 11.0.8. When I run the tomcat server console showing some error.

migration information.

java 1.8 ==> java 11.0.8

Tomcat 8.0.26 (JVM 1.8) ==> Tomcat 9 (JVM 11.0.8)

console error log.

> 2020/10/06 09:19:05.948,[ERROR],main,ContextLoader,Context initialization failed
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'globalValidator' defined in class path resource [spring/root-context.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
> PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'validationMessageSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/validator/spi/resourceloading/ResourceBundleLocator
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1642) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1357) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:578) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:409) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291) [spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103) [spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4682) [catalina.jar:9.0.17]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5150) [catalina.jar:9.0.17]
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [catalina.jar:9.0.17]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377) [catalina.jar:9.0.17]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367) [catalina.jar:9.0.17]
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) [?:?]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) [tomcat-util.jar:9.0.17]
> at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) [?:?]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902) [catalina.jar:9.0.17]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:831) [catalina.jar:9.0.17]
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [catalina.jar:9.0.17]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377) [catalina.jar:9.0.17]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367) [catalina.jar:9.0.17]
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) [?:?]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) [tomcat-util.jar:9.0.17]
> at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) [?:?]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902) [catalina.jar:9.0.17]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) [catalina.jar:9.0.17]
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [catalina.jar:9.0.17]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:423) [catalina.jar:9.0.17]
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [catalina.jar:9.0.17]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:928) [catalina.jar:9.0.17]
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [catalina.jar:9.0.17]
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:634) [catalina.jar:9.0.17]
> at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
> at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
> at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350) [bootstrap.jar:9.0.17]
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492) [bootstrap.jar:9.0.17]
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException: Failed properties: Property 'validationMessageSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/validator/spi/resourceloading/ResourceBundleLocator
> at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:122) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:77) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1638) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
> ... 43 more

root-context.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        ">

    <!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->

    <context:component-scan base-package="ac.co.abc.abd.efcpd.core" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="ac.co.abc.abd.efcpd.common" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="ac.co.abc.abd.testpro" />

    <bean id="globalValidator"
            class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
        <property name="validationMessageSource" ref="messageSource"/>
    </bean>
    
    

    <bean id="messageSource"
            class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:/META-INF/messages"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- PostgreSQL DB -->

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/testpro" />
        <property name="username" value="test" />
        <property name="password" value="test" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:/mybatis/mybatis-config.xml"/>
        <property name="mapperLocations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:/mybatis/mapper/**/*.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate" destroy-method="getExecutorType">
        <constructor-arg ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.session.jdbc.config.annotation.web.http.JdbcHttpSessionConfiguration">
        <property name="maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds" value="1600" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver">
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Referenced Libraries

[image]

[image]